# Django save scientific number

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to find a way to format a scientific number and save it into database. My number is read from a csv file.

model.py

```
class Doc(models.Model):
....
    big=models.BigIntegerField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
for line in csvfile:
    data = Doc()
    data.big=line['big_number']
    data.save()
```

This following code generate this error:

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,02161E+12'

2,02E+12 is the value on csv file when it's read on standart format and 2021610000000 for the number format. I want to store the "2021610000000".
Is there a way to force reading the csv column as number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is malformed. While the int('2,02161E+12') and float('2,02161E+12') would indeed produce that error float('2.02161E+12') would not. So the solution is

```
int( float('2,02161E+12'.replace(',','.')) )
```